# How to send email with attachment(csv file) from code in android

Tags: android, csv, datasource, jakarta-mail, email-attachments

I am not able to send the mail with attachment(csv file)... this is my code.. and i am getting some warning...
i tried with plain/text also but getting same output..
here props is properties file in which i have already added all value of gmail.. (port, host etc).

```
try {           
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(
            new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(),
                    "multipart/mixed"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(user));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);
    message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, recipients);

    MimeBodyPart mbp = new MimeBodyPart();
    mbp.setContent(message, "multipart/mixed");
    FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource(csvFile);
    mbp.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
    mbp.setFileName(fds.getName());

    Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
    mp.addBodyPart(mbp);
    message.setContent(mp);

    SMTPTransport smtpTransport = (SMTPTransport) session
            .getTransport("smtps");
    smtpTransport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", user, password);
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(
            getClass().getClassLoader());
    smtpTransport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getAllRecipients());
    smtpTransport.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am not able to send the mail with attachment(csv file)... this is my code.. and i am getting some warning...
i tried with plain/text also but getting same output..

Comment: You're really going to have to give us more clues...  Exactly **what** warning are you getting?  What does the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?

Comment: Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
 javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
 boundary="----=_Part_22_262821609.1391196807876"
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1167)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:254)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
 at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1391)

Comment: above i copied the log.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21866418/1040885)?