# Unable to send async emails with Play 2.5

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, playframework-2.5

I recently migrated my application from play 2.3 to play 2.5 following this guide https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25
and I update play-mailer too according to what specified here https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer

Now my app is no longer able to send emails. I created an Injector Constructor for injecting mailer instance

```
@Inject public SmtpConnector(MailerClient mailer) 
{ 
    this.mailerClient = mailer; 
    MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap)   MailcapCommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-  handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
    mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
    mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
    mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
    CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc); 
}
```

I execute the send email method in an async task:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> mailerClient.send(email) ).exceptionally(exc -> {exc.printStackTrace(); return null;});
```

But I keep getting an error about the lack of suport about mimetype multipart:

> ...
>   java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1626) ... 5 more Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message; nested exception is: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_0_1284684208.1469102367572" at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1177) at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:195) at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124) at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1411) ... 14 more Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/alternative; boundary="----=_Part_0_1284684208.1469102367572" at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:896) at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:317) at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485) at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1773) at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1121) ... 17 more

But:

- As you can see above, I set them in the Injector constructor
- I did not change anything in the IDE/ClassPath (just the sbt/package versions in build.sbt)
- I tried all what was suggested here [javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856211/javax-activation-unsupporteddatatypeexception-no-object-dch-for-mime-type-multi) but with no results. The current thread context approach leads me to a security exception

Is there a workaround to this? Is there a(nother) way to send emails using a java api with Play framework 2.5?

**UPDATE 1:**

According to jmehrens suggestion, I activated the debug flag, that's what I got:

> Can't load DCH com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed; 
>   Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com/sun/mail/handlers/multipart_mixed

And according to this github.com/playframework/play-mailer/issues/104 the problem seems triggered by not calling the method from the context of the Play controller

**UPDATE 2**:
Here you can find the -verbose:class output from the start till the exception: s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=50323853839855936002

**UPDATE 3**:

Here you can find the classloader of getClass() dumped as suggested by jmehrens:  s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=51200633758480523188

Comment: Is is possible to set the system property `javax.activation.debug=true` add the output to the question?  You should also try to print the classloader tree for `javax.mail.Session`, `javax.activation.DataHandler`, the current context classloader, and the classloader of `mailerClient`.

Comment: Looks like a problem with the layout of the calling classloader.  Were you able to print the classloader tree? [Here is some example code lines 210-215 and lines 268-276](https://java.net/projects/javamail/sources/mercurial/content/logging/src/main/java/MailHandlerDemo.java?rev=838)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This fixes the issue:

```
CompletableFuture.runAsync( () -> {
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader( getClass().getClassLoader() ); 
mailerClient.send(email);}, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()).exceptionally(exc ->  {
exc.printStackTrace(); 
return null;});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think should be a [link to issue](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/issues/104) here.