# Android Smali - javax.mail not found

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, smali, apktool

I created an Android application that sends emails via [JavaMail](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) and it works fine. Now I need to get the Smali code to put it in another application (school projects, don't worry).

However if I "decompile" the apk file with [apktool](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/) and (without making any changes) I rebuild it, the application does not seem to find the necessary classes.

`adb logcat` shows:

`W javax.mail: expected resource not found: {0}`

And consequently a series of errors:

```
W System.err: javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
W System.err:   nested exception is:
W System.err:   javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
W System.err:   boundary="----=_Part_0_234635997.1537189564327"
W System.err:   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1365)
W System.err:   at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
W System.err:   at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
W System.err:   at com.example.sec.screentest.MainActivity$MailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:164)
W System.err:   at com.example.sec.screentest.MainActivity$MailTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:124)
W System.err:   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:345)
W System.err:   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
W System.err:   at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:257)
W System.err:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
W System.err:   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
W System.err:   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:784)
W System.err: Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
W System.err:   boundary="----=_Part_0_234635997.1537189564327"
W System.err:   at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:908)
W System.err:   at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:330)
W System.err:   at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1694)
W System.err:   at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1913)
W System.err:   at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1315)
W System.err:   ... 10 more
```

Looking at the Smali code, `javax.mail` is always called from the project "root" (e.g: `Ljavax/mail/Authenticator;-><init>()V`) and this should be correct since the `javax` folder is in that position.

I'm using: `apktool d appname.apk` and `apktool b project_dir` to rebuild.

Comment: How are you decompiling and recompiling (which options are you using)?

Comment: No options (probably this is the problem!).
I'm using: `apktool d appname.apk` and `apktool b project_dir` to rebuild.

Comment: Try `apktool b -c project_dir`. `-c` keeps the original signature, which includes the META-INF folder, which apparently contains JavaMail resources.

Comment: It works! Thank you very much. I write an "answer" to mark it as "solved".

Comment: I suppose the underlying reason for this should be linked with the appropriate existing item: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21856211/1531971

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems JavaMail stores resources inside your app's META-INF folder. Usually with Android, this is where the app's signature is stored, so APKTool avoids including it by default when you rebuild (using it would mean you couldn't remove resources or edit the manifest).

APKTool has an option for building: `-c`. This will retain the original signature by copying the entire META-INF folder into the new APK. You usually don't want to use this option, since as I said above, it means you can't remove resources or edit the manifest, but for this, it'll do what you need.

If there's ever a time when you can't use the original signature, you can probably manually find the JavaMail files and copy them into the new META-INF folder created after resigning the APK.

Comment: I think the Activation resources need to be signed as well.

Comment: @jdv could be. I don't know enough about JavaMail, just how APKTool works.

Comment: Resources are part of the checksums used for signatures, so changing them will break the APK.

Comment: @jdv I can say with absolute certainty that you can change Android app resources and maintain the original signature. You may not be able to install the new APK normally, but as the developer of a set of mods for the LG V20, I know for a fact that you can change the resource and use the original signature, as long as you install manually.

Comment: Dev-signing and ADB offers all sorts of holes, yes. I was talking about a real signed deliverable (even from your own app server.)

Comment: I don't think that's what's happening here. At least, I hope not. This project shouldn't go anywhere near production.

Comment: It's unclear who the eventual consumer is, but agreed. It sort of looks like a hack of other code shoved into a new package. It depends on what the consumer of that final package expects...

Comment: The consumer is the professor of a "malware" course. It worked by manually adding the files to META-INF and then resigning the whole package (using `jarsigner`). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly your build process has stripped out some or all of the META-INF resources from the associated Activation library required by JavaMail. These are mailer and message resources provided by Activation that need to be on the classpath at runtime.

This is the usual reason for the "no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed" messages in stacktraces.

Since I don't *fully* understand how you are building your deliverable, I can only recommend:

- Use [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android). This minimizes the dangling references that will never be found in the Android runtime, and provides a minimal Activation library.
- Make sure your build system does not strip out the META-INF resources from Activation. (Based on a comment from another contributor I don't want to disappear, this might mean invoking something like `apktool b -c project_dir`; `-c` preserves the original signature, which includes the META-INF folder.)

This might also mean you need to look closely at Proguard (if you use it) to make sure this is also not stripping out anything found by Reflection, etc.