# javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type text/calendar;method=REQUEST

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, icalendar, outlook-calendar

I am trying send calendar meeting invite using java mail. But am facing below error. i have searched on stack overflow. All answers with related error are for mail.

**no object DCH for MIME type text/calendar;method=REQUEST**

code :

```
BodyPart calendarPart = new MimeBodyPart();
calendarPart.addHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");
calendarPart.setContent(calendarContent, "text/calendar;method=REQUEST");

Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(calendarPart);

MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");
message.setSubject(meetingSubject);
message.setContent(multipart);

Transport.send(message);
```

Error Trace:

```
  Caused by: javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type text/calendar;method=REQUEST 
 at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:885) 
 at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316) 
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485) 
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:865) 
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:462) 
 at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:103) 
 at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:883) 
 at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:316) 
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1485) 
 at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1773) 
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1121)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21856211/javax-activation-unsupporteddatatypeexception-no-object-dch-for-mime-type-multi)

Comment: @Scratte , This answer is related to only mail. whereas i am sending meeting invite along with mail.

Comment: What is the Spring Boot version you are using?

Comment: spring boot version 1.5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue got resolved.
Update Mail to 1.4.7.
Also, there were some issues on the server-side related to the Amazon SES service.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem a few days ago, and just today I found a solution that solved 100% my problem.

JavaMail depends on some configuration files to map MIME types to Java classes (e.g., multipart/mixed to javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart). These configuration files are loaded using the ClassLoader for the application. If the ClassLoader doesn't function properly (in my case due to dependency conflicts), these configuration files won't be found.

Just add the following code to the beggining of your method:

```
final MimetypesFileTypeMap mimetypes = (MimetypesFileTypeMap) MimetypesFileTypeMap.getDefaultFileTypeMap();
mimetypes.addMimeTypes("text/calendar ics ICS");
final MailcapCommandMap mailcap = (MailcapCommandMap) MailcapCommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
mailcap.addMailcap("text/calendar;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
```

I hope it is not too late and that it can help you all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no class configured that knows how to convert a calendarContent object (whatever that is) to a byte stream in the format of the MIME type text/calendar.  If you can do that conversion yourself, by converting the object to a byte array or a String, then JavaMail can handle it without further configuration.  If you want to configure the system to be able to do that conversion for you, you'll need to configure the JavaBeans Activation Framework, and you'll need to supply a class that does the conversion.  Since you're only doing this yourself and not trying to make it easy for others, the simplest approach is what I described first - convert the calendarContent object to a byte array/stream or a String.

Comment: calendarContent is already string. After your suggestion i have tried to convert same to byte array (calendarContent.getBytes() ) but still same issue. any other suggestion ?

Comment: JavaMail doesn't have any special knowledge of text/calendar and it doesn't assume that text/* can be represented by a String, although perhaps it should.  For now, use ByteArrayDataSource with the String and the MIME type text/calendar.  Set the content using something like this: `calendarPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(
  new ByteArrayDataSource(calendarContent, "text/calendar")));`

Comment: You'll also need to get rid of all of those addHeaderLine calls; you should almost never use that method.  Instead, you probably need to add those as parameters to the text/calendar MIME type.  You can do that as a string, or you can use the ContentType class to make sure to get the syntax correct.