# Unsupported data type when getting mail JPG images

Tags: java, email, png, jpeg

I'm trying to get the inline images of a mail, for which I have the following code:

```
protected void setCidAttachments(Message message, MensajeEmail mensajeEmail) {

    try {

        MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) message.getDataHandler().getContent();

        for (int k = 0; k < mimeMultipart.getCount(); k++) {

            MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(k);
            processPart(part, mensajeEmail);

        }

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error obtendo adxuntos con cid", e);
    }

}

private void processPart (BodyPart part, MensajeEmail mensajeEmail) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    String type = getContentType(part);
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(mensajeEmail.getContenido());

    if (isImage(type) && part.getDataHandler() != null && part.getDataHandler().getContent() != null) {

        if (part.getDataHandler().getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {

            MimeMultipart p = (MimeMultipart) part.getDataHandler().getContent();

            for (int i = 0; i < p.getCount(); i++) {

                BodyPart subpart = p.getBodyPart(i != p.getCount() - 1 ? i + 1 : i);
                processPart(subpart, mensajeEmail);

            }

        } else {

            mensajeEmail.setContenido(getInlineImage(part, content));

        }

    }

}

private String getInlineImage (BodyPart part, StringBuilder content) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    Base64 decoder64 = new Base64();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // Get type

    String type = getContentType(part);

    // Get Content-ID

    String contentId = getContentId(part);

    // Replace

    if (contentId.length() > 0) {

        part.getDataHandler().writeTo(bos);
        int start = content.indexOf("src=\"cid:" + contentId + "\"") + 5;

        if (start > 4) {

            int length = contentId.length() + 4;
            content.replace(start, start + length, "data:" + (isImage(type) ? type : "image/png;") + " base64," + decoder64.encodeToString(bos.toByteArray()));

        }

    }

    bos.close();

    return content.toString();

}

private String getContentId (BodyPart part) throws MessagingException {

    Enumeration headers = part.getAllHeaders();

    while (headers.hasMoreElements()) {

        Header header = (Header)headers.nextElement();

        if (header.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Content-ID"))
            return cleanContentId(header.getValue());

    }

    return "";

}

private String getContentType (BodyPart part) throws MessagingException {

    return part.getContentType().split(" ")[0];

}

private boolean isImage (String mime) {

    return !mime.equals("text/html;") && !mime.equals("text/plain;");

}

private String cleanContentId (String contentId) {

    if (contentId.charAt(0) == '<') contentId = contentId.substring(1, contentId.length() - 1);
    return contentId;

}
```

This works perfectly fine when I send PNG images (which makes me think my code is indeed correct). However, when I try to send a JPG image, I get the following exception:

```
javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: Unknown image type image/jpeg; name=sony-car-796x418.jpg
at org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.AbstractImageHandler.getContent(AbstractImageHandler.java:57)
at javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:795)
at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:542)
at es.enxenio.fcpw.plinper.daemons.email.AbstractProtocoloObtencionEmail.processPart(AbstractProtocoloObtencionEmail.java:378)

...
```

Is the framework really not able to work with JPG images? Is there some way I can fix this?

EDIT: Gmail doesn't even let me send JPG images so it's probably not a very common format for mail images, which makes me think might not be widely implemented and that could be the reason why Java doesn't seem to be able to work with it

Comment: See answers to earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/q/21856211/5427593

Comment: Thanks! Will take a look

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. This line

```
if (isImage(type) && part.getDataHandler() != null && part.getDataHandler().getContent()
```

shouldn't check whether the type is an image but whether it is a multipart. Otherwise we could be processing a jpg image as a multipart. For some reason png images don't mind this and that's why it was working. Here are the changed parts of the code:

```
protected void setCidAttachments(Message message, MensajeEmail mensajeEmail) {

    try {

        processPart(message, mensajeEmail);

    }

    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error obtendo adxuntos con cid", e);
    }

}

private void processPart(Part part, MensajeEmail mensajeEmail) throws MessagingException, IOException {

    String type = getContentType(part);
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder(mensajeEmail.getContenido());

    if (isMultipart(type) && part.getDataHandler() != null && part.getDataHandler().getContent() != null && part.getDataHandler().getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {

        MimeMultipart multipart = (MimeMultipart) part.getDataHandler().getContent();

        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {

            BodyPart subpart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
            processPart(subpart, mensajeEmail);

        }

    } 

    else {

        mensajeEmail.setContenido(getInlineImage(part, content));

    }

}

private boolean isMultipart(String mime) {

    return (Pattern.matches("multipart/.*", mime));

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got a similar exception running an app on eclipse osgi with java 11 and with bundles javax.mail.glassfish 1.4.1 and javax.activation 1.1.0 (got these 2 from https://eclipse.org/orbit):

```
javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: Unknown image type image/jpeg; name=image001.jpg
  at org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.AbstractImageHandler.getContent(AbstractImageHandler.java:57)
  at javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:147)
  at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getContent(MimeBodyPart.java:652)
  at my.code.calling.getcontent.MyClass(MyClass.java:802)
```

The package org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers is included in the javax.transaction 1.1.0 bundle.

I resolved the problem by #-commenting the image/gif, image/jpeg handlers in the file META-INF/mailcap inside the javax.activation bundle:

```properties
## <apache license disclaimer> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
##
## $Rev$ $Date: 2008/04/09 19:25:23 $
##

text/plain;;    x-java-content-handler=org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.TextPlainHandler
text/html;;     x-java-content-handler=org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.TextHtmlHandler
text/xml;;      x-java-content-handler=org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.TextXmlHandler

#image/gif;;     x-java-content-handler=org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.ImageGifHandler
#image/jpeg;;    x-java-content-handler=org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.ImageJpegHandler

multipart/*;;   x-java-content-handler=org.apache.geronimo.activation.handlers.MultipartHandler
```

There's no image/png here, that's why pngs are not a problem in the first place.
So by commenting gif and jpeg handlers, attachments of these types are now handled like pngs: getContent() will just yield an InputStream, instead of an AWT Image, which I think those geronimo ImageHandlers would produce if everything worked as intended.

Some internals: Geronimo AbstractImageHandler of javax.activation 1.1.0 tries to determine the type of image from javax.mail.glassfish 1.4.1 method IMAPBodyPart.getContent(), but this returns the mime-type incl. parameters, e.g. "image/jpeg; name=sony-car-796x418.jpg", which isn't understood and ultimately leads to the UnsupportedDataTypeException.

javax.mail.glassfish also has an META-INF/mailcap file, whose image/* section interestingly looks like this:

```properties
# can't support image types because java.awt.Toolkit doesn't work on servers
#
#image/gif;;        x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.image_gif
#image/jpeg;;       x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.image_jpeg
```

That could be a lead, I still did get the original jpeg exception also in a gui application, though.

Another thing, this error doesn't occur for me when running the same setup with java 8 instead of 11, probably got something to do with java 8 having its own javax.activation package.